# многомерный массив c++

Tags: c++, массивы

Задание на работу: В матрице Z(5,6) первый отрицательный элемент каждого
столбца заменить суммой оставшихся. Отрицательные элементы до замены
вывести в массив B. Вывести исходную и преобразованную матрицы,
полученный массив. Мучаюсь с этим заданием на протяжении 2х недель. Вывел массив B, не могу придумать как записать в место отрицательных символов сумму из символов которые стояли в одном столбце с отрицательным.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    static const int N = 5, M = 6;
    int Z[N][M] = { {-1, -2,-3,-4,-5,-6},

    { 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5},

    { 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5},

    { 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5},

    { 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5} }, i, j, k = 0, nm, B[6];

    std::cout << "Массив B: " << "\n";
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (Z[j][i] < 0)
            {
                if (k == 0)
                {
                    B[i] = Z[j][i];
                    std::cout << B[i] << std::endl;
                    k = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    int summ = 0;
    int idx = -1;
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        if ((Z[j][i] < 0) &  (idx == -1)) 
        {
            B[i] = Z[j][i];
            std::cout << B[i] << std::endl;
            idx = i;
        }
        else 
           summ += (Z[j][i];
    }
    if (idx >= 0)
        Z[j][i] = summ;
}
```